# int array but the indices are characters?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

I am confused how is it possible to have an integer array while the indices are characters?
Another confusion is this line

`if(i + 1 < N && nums[s[i+1]] > nums[s[i]])`

is the string getting converted to an integer which then gets mapped to the nums array similar to a hashing it to an index?`

```
 int romanToInt(string s) {
            const int N = s.length();
            int nums[128];
            nums['I'] = 1;
            nums['V'] = 5;
            nums['X'] = 10;
            nums['L'] = 50;
            nums['C'] = 100;
            nums['D'] = 500;
            nums['M'] = 1000;
            int result = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                if(i + 1 < N && nums[s[i+1]] > nums[s[i]])
                    result -=  nums[s[i]]; 
                else
                    result += nums[s[i]];
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Character literals can be converted to a integer.  BTW, everything is stored as a number in the computer.

Comment: Characters are ASCII values that are treated as integers when indexing an array. For example, the ASCII value of `I`, represented by `'I'` is 73 (decimal).

Comment: Your code have *undefined behavior* by the way, because you use uninitialized elements of `nums`. Uninitialized variables (or array elements) will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random/garbage) value, and using these values leads to said undefined behavior.

Comment: "*is the string getting converted*": Note that the index here is *not a string*. It is a (single) *character*. It would not work with a string as index. There is no hashing of anything involved.

Comment: @walnut i ment at  nums[s[i+1]]

Comment: @sanjep `s` is a string, so `s[i+1]` is a character, not a string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Does he really use uninitialized elements? I doubt that, unless the input-string contains something other than IVXLCDM. But in that case, you should also warn him about characters beyond basic ASCII being below zero or above 127, depending on whether plain char is signed.

Comment: Note that this example relies on the encoding being ASCII (or at least an encoding where these letters have a numerical value between 0 and 128). If the encoding was, e.g., EBCDIC, the program would access memory outside of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a value of a type smaller than `int` is used in an arithmetic expression (like for example as operator to the array index operator), it is [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) to `int`.

But note that the array element type and the index type isn't really related.

Comment: for example  nums['I'] = 1 , might equal to  nums[20] = 1 and then nums[s[i]] will be nums[20]=1 which will give 1

Comment: @sanjep Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

`char`s are really just numbers. They're one-byte integers. You have `int`s and you have `short`s and you have `char`s.

Their numerical value (which you can observe via conversion or promotion to another integer type like `int` then print it out) is, when initialised from a character literal, often the ASCII code of the glyph in that literal. Array indices undergo promotion to `int` so you're just using `int`s really. There's no magic here.

The notion that `char`s are "characters" isn't really true; it's just that many formatting/output functions treat them specifically so that it kind of seems like they are. A "character" is (variously) either an abstract concept (e.g. Unicode character U+0056, which can be represented in a variety of ways depending on the chosen encoding) or the shape of a glyph ("the letter A"); `char` provides neither of those pieces of information (a character *literal* sort of does, as described above). It's got a bad name but that comes from the olden days.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all the characters are represented by their ASCII values as are other symbols in C++.
You can checkout the ASCII table here by clicking on this link https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html.So,In this line of code nums['V'] = 5 can also be written as nums[86]=5 as V is represented as 86 in ASCII table.

Further  nums[s[2]]==to saying nums[The ASCII value of the character at the 3rd position in the string s].
I hope this is helful.